# accessing loop variable in a loop

Tags: shell-script

This is my script:

```
load_1=15231
load_2=20547
load_3=24561
load_4=22874
f4=434

   sum_1=`expr $load_1 + $f4`
   sum_2=`expr $load_2 + $f4`
   sum_3=`expr $load_3 + $f4`
   sum_4=`expr $load_4 + $f4`

   min=$sum_1
   LIST1="1 2 3 4"
   for x in $LIST1
    do
     if [ $sum_$x -lt $min ]
      then
       min=$sum_$x
       f3=$x
     fi
    done
   echo $min
   echo $f3
```

below is the output while executing the script using `bash -x`:

```
+ load_1=15231
+ load_2=20547
+ load_3=24561
+ load_4=22874
+ f4=434
++ expr 15231 + 434
+ sum_1=15665
++ expr 20547 + 434
+ sum_2=20981
++ expr 24561 + 434
+ sum_3=24995
++ expr 22874 + 434
+ sum_4=23308
+ min=15665
+ LIST1='1 2 3 4'
+ for x in '$LIST1'
+ [[ 1 -lt 15665 ]]
+ min=1
+ f3=1
+ for x in '$LIST1'
+ [[ 2 -lt 1 ]]
+ for x in '$LIST1'
+ [[ 3 -lt 1 ]]
+ for x in '$LIST1'
+ [[ 4 -lt 1 ]]
+ echo 1
1
+ echo 1
1
```

the value of loop variable 'x' has to be substituted in the test condition variable `sum_x` and then value of `$sum_x` has to be given to the test condition. But as shown in the output, the value of 'x' is directly taken in the condition. I have tried various combinations of quotes and paranthesis but nothing worked for me. Please help!!

Comment: Could you explain what your script is supposed to be doing? As far as I can tell, you are checking whether any of the sums is less than the 1st one and, if so, set `min` to that sum and `f3` to the relevant index. In your example, however, that would never be true and `f3` would never be set. Please [edit] and explain _in words_ what output you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `$sum_$x` is interpreted as the concatenation of `$sum_` and `$x`:

```
~$ for x in $LIST1;  do   echo $sum_$x;  done
1
2
3
4
```

Hence your problem. What you want is using

```
~$ for x in $LIST1;  do   echo $((sum_$x));  done
15665
20981
24995
23308
```

Comment: @FredtantiniThanks for your solution....it is working
is there any way to initialize the values of sum_1 to sum_4 in a loop as below
LIST1="1 2 3 4"
    for j in $LIST1
    do
       sum_$j=`expr $((load_$j)) + $f4`
    done

because when i am executing this script, iam getting "command not found error"

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your script is supposed to be doing and you haven't told us what language you are writing in. I will therefore assume bash and that you are aware of the fact that the values you have in your question don't make your script [do anything very useful](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208428/accessing-loop-variable-in-a-loop#comment352253_208428).

In general, concatenating strings to get a variable name is both quite cumbersome and unneeded. Just use arrays instead:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
load=(15231 20547 24561 22874)
f4=434

for((i=0;i<${#load[@]};i++))
do
    sums[i]=$((${load[i]} + $f4))
done

min=$((${sums[0]}))
for((i=1;i<${#load[@]};i++))
do
    if [ "${sums[i]}" -lt "$min" ]
    then
       min="${sums[i]}"
       f3="$i"
    fi
done

printf "%s\n%s" "$min" "$f3"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. a more bash way for what you need:

try this:

```
load_1=15231  
load_2=20547  
load_3=24561
load_4=22874
f4=434
line=`(set -o posix ; set) | grep load_  | sort -t = -n -k2 | head -1`
min=`echo $line | cut -d= -f2`
echo $((min+f4))
echo $line | cut -d= -f1 | cut -d_ -f2
```

This results in:

`15665
1`

if you want to use your code anyway:

2. you can avoid using `LIST1` by `for x in {1..4}`
3. set `f3=1` when you set `min`, otherwise - as in your example - it isn't set

Answer (score 0):

```
load_1=15231
load_2=20547
load_3=24561
load_4=22874
f4=434
min=0
f3=1

for n in 1 2 3 4
do   [ "$((sum_$n=load_$n+f4))" -lt \
       "$((min=min?min:sum_$n))" ] &&
     min=$((sum_$n)) f3=$n
     printf '$%s =\t%d\n' \
            "sum_$n" "$((sum_$n))" \
             min "$min" f3 "$f3"
done
```

The math expansion will expand the shell variables *first*. When it does it will arrive at a statement that looks like:

```
sum_[1234] = load_[1234] + f4
```

...where the brackets represent each iteration in the loop, and which is valid arithmetic syntax because strings represent variable names for integers in a shell arithmetic expansion. It will set those variables in the current shell context even when it is used as an argument to `[ test ]` - so `$sum_1` is simultaneously set to the value *15231* and compared to `$min` which is `0`.

But based on your values `$min` is never adjusted according to `$sum_$n` because no value for `$sum_$n` is ever less than `$min`.

#### OUTPUT

```
$sum_1 =    15665
$min =  15665
$f3 =   1
$sum_2 =    20981
$min =  15665
$f3 =   1
$sum_3 =    24995
$min =  15665
$f3 =   1
$sum_4 =    23308
$min =  15665
$f3 =   1
```

In fact, we could put the entire thing in a single math expansion and leave the test out entirely:

```
load_1=15231
load_2=20547
load_3=24561
load_4=22874
f4=434
f3=$((!(min=0)))
for n in 1 2 3 4
do  echo \$min = "$((
           min = ( min    >  ( sum_$n = load_$n+f4 ) )
               ? ( sum_$n + !( f3     = $n         ) )
               : ( min    ?    min    : sum_$n     )
))"; done
```

That sets all variables appropriately for every iteration, but only expands to `$min`'s value each time. It prints:

```
$min = 15665
$min = 15665
$min = 15665
$min = 15665
```